# Animated basic Vector plot

Tags: plotting, graphics, animation

what codes are needed to properly animate a vector plot?
this for example: VectorPlot[{y, -x}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}].
because i tried everything, i have read the help manual, and searched in youtube tutorials but i couldn't do it.

Comment: What do you mean with animate? What do you want to animate? The vector field you gave is static the only thing there you could animate would be plot parameters or the field itself. Mathematica has the `Animate` and `Manipulate` function for this.

Comment: My teacher just told us to make a vector field 2D and 3D to move ("animate"), but i have never used mathematica before.

Comment: Look at the Documentation for `Animate` and put in your vector plot instead of the normal plot from the example. Then you just need to chose what quantity you want to animate. The field itself could be one option: `Animate[VectorPlot[{y, u*x}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}], {u, -2, 2}]`

Comment: thanks really, yes thats exactly what i didn't know how to do it.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 16):

Here is one possibility:

```
Clear[dx, dy, f, points, fmap, stages, stuff]

dx[x_, y_] := -9 y + (3 x^2 y)/4;
dy[x_, y_] := -9 x + x^3/4;
Clear[f]
f[{x_, y_}] := {0, 0} /; \[Not] (-10 <= x <= 10.1);
f[{x_, y_}] := {0, 0} /; \[Not] (-10 <= y <= 10.1);
f[{x_, y_}] := {x + .001 dx[x, y] , y + .001 dy[x, y]};


 points = Partition[Table[RandomReal[{-4, 4}], 200], 2, 1]~Join~
          Partition[Table[RandomReal[{-10, 10}], 200], 2, 1];




  Clear[fmap];
  fmap[{stuff___}] := f /@ {stuff};
  stages = NestList[fmap, points, 100];
  stages = stages /. {x_Real, y_Real} /; \[Not](-10 < x < 10) :>{0,0};



    stuff = Show[StreamPlot[{-9 y + (3 x^2 y)/4, -9 x + x^3/4}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
    PlotTheme -> "Minimal"],
    Graphics@{Red, PointSize[.015], Point[stages[[hh]]]},
    PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}
    , Axes -> True]~Table~{hh, 1, 100, 1};


    ListAnimate[stuff]
```

[image]

[image]

idea2

```
 Manipulate[
  VectorPlot[{y - p[[1]], x + p[[2]]}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}],
  {{p, {0, 0}}, Locator}]
```

another one
[image]
[image]

```
Clear[dx, dy, f, points, fmap, stages, stuff]

dx[x_, y_] := y^3 - 9 x ;
dy[x_, y_] := x^3 - 9 y ;

f[{x_, y_}] := {0, 0} /; \[Not] (-10 <= x <= 10.1);
f[{x_, y_}] := {0, 0} /; \[Not] (-10 <= y <= 10.1);
f[{x_, y_}] := {x + .001 dx[x, y], y + .001 dy[x, y]};

points = Partition[Table[RandomReal[{-4, 4}], 200], 2, 1]~Join~
         Partition[Table[RandomReal[{-10, 10}], 200], 2, 1];


fmap[{stuff___}] := f /@ {stuff};
stages = NestList[fmap, points, 100];
stages = stages /.{x_Real, y_Real} /; \[Not] (-10 < x < 10) :> {0,0};


stuff = Show[
    StreamPlot[
         {    y^3 - 9 x   ,     x^3 - 9 y  },
         {x, -10, 10},
         {y, -10, 10},
         PlotTheme -> "Minimal"
       ],
         Graphics@{Red, PointSize[.015], Point[stages[[hh]]]}, 
         PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}},
         Axes -> True
 ]~Table~{hh, 1, 100, 1};


 ListAnimate[stuff]
```

Comment: maybe change the points to vectors will have a better visual effect :) very impressive! +1

Comment: good idea! I will try to do that.  @Wjx

Comment: Also, you can ramdomly generate points in the animation process, so the dynamic can keep going.

Comment: http://www.falstad.com/vector/     probably the best simulation on the internet

Comment: another nice javascript simulation https://anvaka.github.io/fieldplay/